# Postman: Duplicated tests in collection run

Tags: api, rest, postman

I am creating some automatized tests for rest API in postman, and I have a little problem here:

I have some test script within the request. When I run this request alone, everything is fine, and in "Test Results" I can see exact number of tests. (not less, not more).

When I run whole collection with "collection runner", there is a problem. For every request, there are duplicated tests and order of tests is also weird.

I can't show these methods, but for example:
I am checking attributes, which are in reply body. In my `for` cycle, I am getting names of attributes and checking parsed body, if attribute with given name exists, then test is passed.
When I run collection as a whole, then some of these attributes are checked twice (not all of them) and in different order, then they are in array.

I can demonstrate problem on these two screenshots with status check (also duplicated).

[image: duplicated request]

[image: test script]

Any suggestions how to fix this? I found some reports of this thing on internet, but no solution at all.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you make a reproducable sample? With 2 images, it's kind of hard to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Are there any scripts under the collection's Test tab?

Comment: There isn't. Only Pre-request script which saving function into global variable, so I am able to call that function within test scripts in requests.